# 400 Bad Request received using java.net.HTTPClient, but working fine with Spring RestTemplate & Postman on the same URL & body

Tags: spring-boot, httprequest, httpclient, resttemplate

I am trying to send a JSON POST request to a URL using HTTPClient in my Springboot application, but I am receiving a 400 status response from the server.
However, when I send the same request using Postman, I receive the desired response from the server.

Here's my code:

```
// some dummy url:
String url = "http://88.22.199.111:5000/detect";

JSONObject json1 = new JSONObject();
json1.put("From", "Sawan");
json1.put("to", "Mohan");
json1.put("message", "is API working?");
json1.put("check_list", 1);

HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.newBuilder().build();

HttpRequest httpRequest = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
        .uri(URI.create(url))
        .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
        .POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString(json1.toString()))
        .build();

System.out.println(json1.toString());
HttpResponse<String> httpResponse = httpClient.send(httpRequest, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());

System.out.println(httpResponse.statusCode());
System.out.println(httpResponse.body());
```

This is the output on the console:

```
{"check_list":1,"From":"Sawan","to":"Mohan","message":"is API working?"}
400
{"message": "The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand."}
```

When I hit the same URL via Postman with the following details, I get the desired response from the server:

Request Type: POST

URL: same URL as above

cURL:

```
curl --location 'http://88.22.199.111:5000/detect' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '{
    "From":"Sawan"
    ,"to":"Mohan"
    ,"message":"is API working?"
    ,"check_list":1
} '
```

Desired Output:

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "message": "Success",
    "timestamp": "2023-03-31 05:20:33.455868 +0000",
    "data": {
        "Message": "is API working?",
        "MessageTimeUTC": "Fri, 31 Mar 2023 05:20:33 GMT",
        "Message_By": "sawan",
        "Message_To": "mohan",
        "Message_Intended_For": "mohan",
        "Sentences": []
}
```

Also, when I use the RestTemplate class, it works fine and I get the desired output on the console but in the actual application I can't use RestTemplate class of springboot so I need help with this.

Is there anything wrong with my code? Do I need to include any additional headers in my request? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please do the following and add to the question. Add a System.out.println(json1.toString()); above the send and add output. Get the curl for the request that works from Postman using the ‘</>’ on the right.

Comment: Added these to the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this will get you closer. I don't have access to your server.

I have compared what java.net.http.HttpClient sends with what Postman/cURL sends. The only differences I can see are the `Accept`, `Upgrade` & `Http2-Settings` headers, which I have added to the code below. The `User-Agent` header is not important. This *should* not make a difference but perhaps the server you are calling is very particular, eg it can't do http2.

For these sorts of issues I find it very useful to fire requests at httpbin.org. It responds with everything it received.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.http.HttpClient;
import java.net.http.HttpRequest;
import java.net.http.HttpResponse;

import org.json.JSONObject;

public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {
        String url = "http://88.22.199.111:5000/detect";
        // or url = "http://httpbin.org/post"; // this is very helpful

        JSONObject json1 = new JSONObject();
        json1.put("From", "Sawan");
        json1.put("to", "Mohan");
        json1.put("message", "is API working?");
        json1.put("check_list", 1);

        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient
            .newBuilder()
            .version(Version.HTTP_1_1) // added this
            .build();

        HttpRequest httpRequest = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                .uri(URI.create(url))
                .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .header("Accept", "*/*") // added this
                .POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString(json1.toString()))
                .build();

        System.out.println(json1.toString());
        HttpResponse<String> httpResponse = httpClient.send(httpRequest, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());

        System.out.println(httpResponse.statusCode());
        System.out.println(httpResponse.body());
    }
}
```

Perhaps also try `RestTemplate` to compare the working headers & payload with the failing ones.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!

I tried this with HTTP client and RestTemplate:

The HTTP client is sending these headers:

    "Http2-Settings": "AAEAAEAAAAIAAAABAAMAAABkAAQBAAAAAAUAAEAA", 
    "Upgrade": "h2c", 
    "User-Agent": "Java-http-client/11.0.2",
    "Accept": "*/*",

Rest Template sends these: 

"User-Agent": "Java/11.0.2",
"Accept": "text/plain, application/json, application/*+json, */*"

I tried adding 'user-agent' and 'accept' as in the rest template but still got 400.

Comment: Oh dear - very mysterious. The User-Agent header is not important. The 'Accept' (case sensitive) might be. However  "Http2-Settings": "AAEAAEAAAAIAAAABAAMAAABkAAQBAAAAAAUAAEAA", "Upgrade": "h2c" could be the problem. Try setting your http version to 1.1 with version(Version.HTTP_1_1). I have updated the answer to reflect.

Comment: Adding the HTTP version worked. Thank you so much!!!